# Нужны ли вопросительные знаки?

Tags: знак

Нужно ли в конце следующих предложений ставить вопросительный знак? Да и вообще хорошо бы проверить знаки препинания... :) Спасибо.

> Цель такого увеличения заключалась в поиске ответа на вопрос,
>   насколько эффективно данное изменение параметров в сторону увеличения?
>   Также требовалось получить ответы на 3 вопроса:
>
> - каковы оптимальные размеры;
> - какое расположение наиболее эффективно;
> - насколько это увеличит КПД?

Answer (score 1):

Вопросительные знаки не нужны. Ведь вопрос только косвенный, не прямой.

По знакам препинания всё хорошо, на мой взгляд. Вот тройку лучше написать словом вместо цифры. Цифры обычно используют с единицами измерения или если число большое.